# Regex to match words separated by one dot after particular set of words until whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to grab the schemaName.tableName from the string containing SQL query.

For example

```
Select t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3, to.column4 from ABC.TABLE1 t1 inner join XYZ.TABLE2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id;
```

After regex match I should get an array containing schemaName.tableName

[ABC.TABLE1,XYZ.TABLE2]

This pattern should be able to fetch schemaName.tableName from any SQL query.

How can I create this pattern please help me.

I tried following but didnt got result

https://regex101.com/r/D82EJh/1

```
[^\/,\s\?#]+?\.[^\/,\s]+?(?=\/|\s|$|\?|#)
```

Comment: What about `[A-Z]+.TABLE[0-9]+` ?

Comment: ABC/XYZ will contain actual schema name in real time data . Same with TABLE1/TABLE2 will be actual table names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This pattern should be able to fetch schemaName.tableName from any SQL query.

To complete the task in this formulation, you will need to organize a whole project, the success of which will nevertheless depend on the chosen dialect of the sql language.
Perhaps you will be satisfied with solving a simpler problem: how to get an array of words (including dots) that follow the words "from" or "join".
Then I propose such a solution below.

```
const sql = "Select t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column3, to.column4 from ABC.TABLE1 t1 inner join XYZ.TABLE2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id;";
console.log(sql);
const regex = /(?<=\b(from|join)\s)(\S+)/g;
const found = sql.match(regex);
console.log(found);
```

This code should show in the console: **['ABC.TABLE1','XYZ.TABLE2']**

Comment: It worked! I agree with you. I have one more criteria in this that comes when I am using subquery in join condition. It fetches (select as well since it is followed by join keyword. I mention it here https://regex101.com/r/D82EJh/2

Answer (score 2):

You could use a capture group, and match the allowed characters:

```
\b(?:join|from)\s+(\w+\.\w+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:join|from)\s+` Match either join or from followed by 1 or more whitespace characters
- `(` Capture group 1 *(that holds the desired value)*

  - `\w+\.\w+` Match 1 or more word characters, then a dot and again 1.or more word characters
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/iUGo1Y/1).

If there should be 1 dot and no more non whitespace characters after the word characters, you could assert a whitespace boundary:

```
\b(?:join|from)\s+(\w+\.\w+)(?!\S)
```